# Spring Converters for @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have InputStream of form field in my Controller, wheter `@RequestParam` is String or MultipartFile. Do anyone know how to properly register converter. What i want achive looks like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
void sendData(@RequestParam("data") InputStream){
   // Deal with InputStream
}
```

I have written two converters, but i'm not sure how to register them in spring boot and force them to work:

```
public class StringToStreamConverter implements Converter<String, InputStream> {

   @Override
   public InputStream convert(String source) {
     return new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes());
   }
}


public class MultipartFileToStreamConverter 
   implements Converter<MultipartFile, InputStream> {

   @Override
   public InputStream convert(MultipartFile source) {
     return source.getInputStream();
   }
}
```

Comment: Look into the `WebDataBinder` and  `@InitBinder` classes.

Comment: `PropertyEditors` are ok with Text Forms,but i don't think they are a good solution for File form, when i just want the content of it.

Comment: That's pretty much the only way to do it with `@RequestParam`. Look into `@RequestBody` for getting the `InputStream` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found somepart solution.

If config class extends `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` i can override method `public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService()` where i can add my converters and it just works.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
   @Override
   public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
       FormattingConversionService f = super.mvcConversionService();
       f.addConverter(new StringToStreamConverter());
       f.addConverter(new MultipartFileToStreamConverter());
       return f;
   }
}
```

I wonder if anyone has better solution.