# Spring Converter<S, T> for @RequestParam and Spring Data REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.6 and Spring Data REST latest release.

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration) states that `Converter<S, T>` instances are auto-registered but it seems to work only for Sping WebMVC. I'm using the Spring Data REST's `@RepositoryRestController` for my controller.

My use case method declaration is the following:

```
public PagedResources<Resource<Equipment>> filterEquipments(
    @RequestParam("page") Integer page,
    @RequestParam("sort") String sort,
    @RequestParam("filter") MyFilter filter, // I want to register custom converter for this type
    PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
    // method body
}
```

The Converter (dummy of it yet):

```
@Component
public class MyFilterConverter implements Converter<String, MyFilter> {
    @Override
    public MyFilter convert(String source) {
        return new MyFilter();
    }
}
```

I have also followed the advice of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22517429/spring-converters-for-requestparam), but it does not seem to work for `@RepositoryRestController` either.

How can I add custom converter to Spring Data REST custom controllers? (Not using manual passing of reference to a converter to the Controller).

Answer (score 3):

Here's *one* solution to register your custom type `Converter` instance(s) at startup (should then be applied to controller method params of type `MyFilter`):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConverterRegistry converterRegistry;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        registerConverters();
    }

    private void registerConverters() {
        converterRegistry.addConverter(new MyFilterConverter());
    }
}
```